# Applying a global name change in Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, entity-framework-5

I have recently changed my EF data model name from X to Y.  Although the name change within solution explorer is visible, however, it doesn't seem to have been registered in Visual Studio 2012.  This can be diagnosed through the auto-generate context designer.cs file still identifying the model with it's old name.  How can I make this name change effective or applied throughout the whole application? More clearly, how do you refactor this name to take effect globally within VS2012?

Comment: There are many things you can rename, so what did you rename? The name of the edmx file in the solution explorer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rename the entity container name, which is in the properties of the edmx. Here's an example:

[image]

As for the namespace: this is not very clear. The namespace entry of the edmx does not seem to do anything, The project's default namespace is used for generated classes. So you should change that to change the namespace of the generated code.

Comment: Thanks Gert, however, it's funny that even though I make the name change through your proposed approach, it still doesn't effectively register and the auto-generated code keep replacing the namespace name into the old name or some random name that it's not meant to do.  What do you think about this strange behavior?

Comment: Please see the addition. The namespace part is not clear to me. But that may be due to the fact that I never really delved into it. You can also change Custom Tool Namespaces of the tt files, but I think this only works on added code generation items.